# typeof(System.Enum).IsClass == false

Tags: .net, reflection, enums, reference-type

Founded that:

```
typeof(System.Enum).IsClass == false
```

It's become strange that `System.Enum` has also `.IsValueType == false`, but Reflector shows that it is really just an `abstract class`.

`System.Enum` is a reference type like a `System.ValueType` and casting enumeration values to/from `System.Enum` reference caused boxing/unboxing. No surprises here.

But what is a reason for `Type` class not to tell truth about `System.Enum` nature?
There is no anything extraordinary with the `System.Enum` type's reflection behavior to make it looks like not a reference type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an issue with .Net 1.1 and 2.0. I haven't checked it in 3.0

From MSDN User [David Bernstein](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/user-125987.aspx)

> The IsClass property of the System.Enum type returns "false", even though "System.Enum" inherits from "System.ValueType" and "typeof(System.ValueType).IsClass" return "true" (as expected). At the same time, typeof(System.Enum).IsValueType returns "false" as expected. This observed behavior seems to contradict the explicit documentation above which stipulates:
>   "This property returns true for Type instances representing Enum and ValueType." I found this to be the case in both frameworks 1.1 and 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

I happened to recently revisit this problem under CLR4 and guess what, it is fixed now. The following definitions:

```
public struct SomeValueType{}

public enum SomeEnum
{
    FirstElement
}
```

with this program

```
Console.WriteLine( typeof( Enum ).IsClass );
Console.WriteLine( typeof( SomeEnum ).IsClass );

Console.WriteLine( typeof( ValueType).IsClass );
Console.WriteLine( typeof( SomeValueType).IsClass );
```

Yields the following results:

```
CLR2: False, False, True, False 
CLR4: True, False, True, False
```