# Getting the type of a "Type" in C# reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

This is harder to find in the docs than I imagined. Anyway, I have some instances of `Type`. How can I find out if they represent classes, methods, interfaces, etc?

```
class Bla { ... }
typeof(Bla).GetKindOrWhatever() // need to get something like "Class"
```

(I'm using Mono on Linux but that shouldn't affect the question, I'm making portable code)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Type.IsClass` might help here. Also `Type.IsInterface`.

Check out...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type_members.aspx

There are quite a few "IsXxxx" properties on Type. Hopefully these will do what you want.

By the way, you should check out other questions on this subject on SO, including this one...

[typeof(System.Enum).IsClass == false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661913/typeofsystem-enum-isclass-false)

... if the types you're going to be checking are enum types, as there are some strange (but predictable) results.

Comment: using that now. what i can't find is an equivalent to type.IsStruct :s

Comment: IsValueType is the closest you're going to get to that. struct is a C# language thing, not a .NET CLR thing. All structs are Value Types. Keep in mind the thing about Enums that I mentioned above though

Comment: Are there any other value types that could appear in Assembly.getExportedMembers()? I doubt primitives will show up there, and those two are the only value types I can think of right now.

Comment: Oh and by the way, just out of curiosity, how are structs then implemented in the CLR?

Answer (score 8):

There are a slew of properties off the Type class.

```
typeof(Bla).IsClass
typeof(Bla).IsInterface
```

etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type_properties.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Type class have some properties that are named IsXXX.
For example it has a IsEnum, IsClass, IsInterface.
If I understand correctly your question this is what you need

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the Type class has various properties that you can use if you just need to know whether your type is a class, interface, delegate, etc.

If you have a Type object and you want to know if it is a specific type, then I recommend using the IsAssignableFrom method found on the Type class:

```
        Type objectType = obj.GetType();
        Type interfaceType = typeof(IExample);

        if (interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
        {
            //...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Type.IsClass Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isclass.aspx)?