# IsClass("className") method?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to know at runtime whether a class name is a class or not?
In other words, is there some sort of method you can use that would tell you whether a string input is a .NET class?

Comment: This sounds like a "[XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)", explain what you are trying to do that the ability to check if a string is a class name or not would be the solution.

Comment: Here is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827425/how-to-check-programatically-if-a-type-is-a-struct-or-a-class

Comment: You may use reflection. Start with this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315665/c-list-all-classes-in-assembly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
bool isClass = false;
Type t = Type.GetType("SomeNameSpace.YourType");
if(t != null)
{
    isClass = t.IsClass;
}
```

I am assuming here that your string input is the namespace/type. I am also assuming that the namespace is defined and available in the context you're running the code in. It will give you a null reference if the type is undefined.

Comment: Type.GetType() will return NULL if "SomeNameSpace.YourType" is not found.

Comment: Besides mentioning it in the text, you might want to update your code example so it does not throw a `NullRefrenceException`