# Instantiating a class depending of generic parameter type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, factory

I'm hitting quite a wall right now and can't find a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to select a class to instantiate depending of the type of my generic parameter. If the generic is a class, instantiate a TestClass ; if it's a struct, instantiate a TestStruct ; if it's an enum, instantiate a TestEnum. These three classes inherit from Test.

The goal of these classes is to avoid boxing when doing comparison.

Here is what my code looks like for now:

```
    public static Test<T> Create()
    {
        return Create(default(T));
    }

    private static Test<U> Create<U>(U arg)
        where U : class
    {
        return TestClass<U>.Create();
    }

    private static Test<U> Create<U>(U? arg)
        where U : struct
    {
        return CreateStruct(arg);
    }

    private static Test<U> CreateStruct<U>(U? arg)
        where U : struct
    {
        if (typeof(U).IsEnum)
        {
            return TestEnum<U>.Create();
        }
        return TestStruct<U>.Create();
    }
```

I get an error in the first Create() function: *The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'U' in the generic type or method 'Test.Create(U)'*

Which makes sense, but how can I get it to work? If I remove the constraint on the second function (where U : class), it compiles but will always call this function, even if I pass an int for instance

I'm using Unity, so the C# standard is rather old, which doesn't help...

Comment: Why is doing this useful?  BTW your question is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  We should be solving for your problem, not your attempted solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check programmatically if a type is a struct or a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827425/how-to-check-programmatically-if-a-type-is-a-struct-or-a-class)

Comment: In my opinion, you're overcomplicating the issue.  As nice as it is to just call the method with the same name, you'll save yourself a lot of hassle if you create one method for reference types, a different one for value types, and depend on the constraints to keep you from using the wrong one.

Comment: @Grax That's what I start to think. It would be easy to do that with C++ templates but I see no clean solution with C# generics