# Why does typeof(System.Enum).IsEnum = false?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

As we know [System.Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a base for all enums, but I wonder why reflection says that it is not enum itself?

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(System.Enum).IsEnum) // says it is false
```

I can't understand the logic, so System.Enum is not enum, but everything that derived from it is enum?

I had a second shock when I saw in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that it is a class

```
public abstract class Enum : ValueType, 
    IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
```

So Enum is a class, however it is value type (derived from special `ValueType` class, which make enum as value type) and is base for all enums, but is not an enum itself :)

Well, if you don't believe that Enum is class, check `typeof(System.Enum).IsClass`

The question is: are there any reason why `IsEnum` is false and `IsClass` is true for a type which is value type and is base for all enums?

```
enum AAA { }
typeof(System.Enum).IsClass //True
typeof(System.Enum).IsEnum  //False
typeof(AAA).IsClass         //False
typeof(AAA).IsEnum          //True
typeof(AAA).BaseType        //System.Enum
```

Comment: Nothing with .NET is as straightforward as you think it should be under the hood!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IL doesn't know structs. IL only has classes.

So, what is a C# struct? It's a sealed class, that extends the `System.ValueType` type. The `System.ValueType` is also what determines what the `IsClass` and `IsStruct` properties of the `Type` class return.

So why does `Type.IsClass` return false? Actually quite simple. While the `Type.IsClass` will really return `false` for an enum, the type you get by e.g. `typeof(Enum)` is not actually `System.Type` - it's `System.RuntimeType`. And `System.RuntimeType` defines the `IsValueTypeImpl` method a bit differently:

```
return !(this == typeof(ValueType)) 
       && !(this == typeof(Enum)) 
       && this.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ValueType));
```

So there's an explicit extra check - the `Enum` type itself, while deriving from `ValueType`, an thus semantically a `struct`, is actually classified as *not* value-type.

But the individual Enum types derived from `System.Enum` are also subclasses of `ValueType`, and aren't the special case of `System.Enum`, so they register as *not* classes.

All in all, do not assume that things that are true for C# also hold for .NET at large. And of course, don't assume that the high-level abstractions still hold in practice - technically, .NET is 100% object oriented, with a single "master" `System.Object` on top of the class hierarchy. Even `System.ValueType` extends (has to) `System.Object`. But - value types are *not* actually `System.Object`; when you *cast* them to `System.Object`, you're creating a *new* object, which wraps the actual value type.

Just like value types in general, .NETs `enum`s are "ugly hacks". They're a special thing as far as the runtime (and a lot of the internal .NET code) is considered, and they're there to simplify things for you as the programmer, or to improve performance (and security, and safety, and ...).

In the end, as you've discovered, some things have to be inconsistent. `Enum` derives from `ValueType`. As per C# semantics, it *should* be a `struct`. But you can't extend a `struct`! And yet, that's what you actually want to do in this case.

I suspect that if enums were to be added to .NET in (say) 5.0, they would be implemented differently. Perhaps just an `IEnum` interface and a couple of extension methods. But extension methods weren't there in C# 1.0, and for value types, they would impose unnecessary performance penalties.

Comment: Thanks, BTW , I just found that the behavior was a bit different in CLR 2 :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661913/typeofsystem-enum-isclass-false

Comment: @ArsenMkrt Very interesting. As far as I'm concerned, it makes more sense that `typeof(Enum).IsClass` is true - after all, there are types derived from `Enum`. In any case, it's a super special case :D

Answer (score 10):

Internally `IsEnum` calls following method

```
IsSubclassOf(RuntimeType.EnumType)
```

with the following implementation(see the comment to the method):

```
        // Returns true if this class is a true subclass of c.  Everything 
        // else returns false.  If this class and c are the same class false is
        // returned. 
        //
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
        [Pure]
        public virtual bool IsSubclassOf(Type c) 
        {
            Type p = this; 
            if (p == c) 
                return false;
            while (p != null) { 
                if (p == c)
                    return true;
                p = p.BaseType;
            } 
            return false;
        }
```

so it only works for descendants of Enum

The IsClass method is even more interesting:

```
public bool IsClass {
            [Pure] 
            get {return ((GetAttributeFlagsImpl() & TypeAttributes.ClassSemanticsMask) == TypeAttributes.Class && !IsValueType);}
        } 
...
 public bool IsValueType {
            [Pure] 
            get {return IsValueTypeImpl();}
        } 
...
 protected virtual bool IsValueTypeImpl() 
        {
            // Note that typeof(Enum) and typeof(ValueType) are not themselves value types. 
            // But there is no point excluding them here because customer derived System.Type
            // (non-runtime type) objects can never be equal to a runtime type, which typeof(XXX) is.
            // Ideally we should throw a NotImplementedException here or just return false because
            // customer implementations of IsSubclassOf should never return true between a non-runtime 
            // type and a runtime type. There is no benefits in making that breaking change though.

            return IsSubclassOf(RuntimeType.ValueType); 
        }
```

It checks for semantics of [class] type, and like you mentioned Enum is a class. And then checks if it is not a value type(see code above)

Comment: I think questions is more about the logic behind it and not how it is implemented... but however post is useful Thanks

Comment: thanks. the logic behind is visible through sequence of methods and comments to them: i.e. IsEnum checks if type is subclass of RuntimeType.EnumType (IsSubclassOff(..)). Next if we read IsSubclassOff method's comment or look at the following lines `Type p = this; if (p == c) return false;`, the picture becomes more clear - IsEnum only works for descendants of Enum. But if you wonder what were they aiming for with this implementation...I cannot answer that.

Comment: In .net we, to some extent, derive from Enum, so it cannot be a value type, cause you cannot derive from value types. So type info says IsClass is true. That's the "logic behind" I can understand. With Enum not being Enum type...maybe because it's an abstract class...you spoiled my day:)

Comment: Yep, I see now, Thanks Andrew!